# Is it possible to NOT embed fonts in a PDF generated with PDFKit?

Tags: cocoa, pdf, embedded-fonts, pdfkit

I'm generating PDF documents with PDFKit and I'd like to have it not embed the standard PDF fonts *(Times, Helvetica, Courier)* if possible.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Once the PDF is produced, you may call other tools to remove these fonts, e.g. [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)
(see [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg34812.html)).

Comment: That's kind of what I was expecting. Was sort of hoping there was something I was missing somewhere in the CGPDF* calls.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone else might chime in. Looks like that won't be happening though :(